# Needing to apply this snippet to a h1 that doesn't contain a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, class

Javascript novice here.
I need a hand understanding how this snippet targets a link and how I can edit it to target a string not wrapped in a link.

At the moment I have this:

```
<h1 class="ProductMeta__Title">
<a href="#">Product title - product feature</a>
</h1>

<script>
  var productMeta = document.querySelectorAll(".ProductMeta__Title");
  function wrapProductName(item, linkClass) {
    if (item === null) return;
    var link = item.querySelector(linkClass);
    var linkText = link.innerHTML;
    var newText = linkText.replace("- ", "<span>");
    if (newText.indexOf("<span>") !== -1) {
        link.innerHTML = newText + "</span>";
    }
}
  productItem.forEach(function (item) {
    wrapProductName(item, ".ProductMeta__Title");
});
</script>
```

This gets rid of a hyphen in my product title and wraps the words after the hyphen in a span so that the product title goes from

"**Product - feature**"
to "**Product** feature"

but it's only applying if I wrap the product title in a link.
How can I edit this to have it apply to

```
<h1 class="ProductMeta__Title">Product title - product feature</h1>
```

Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: what does the variable `item` refer to?

Answer (score 1):

I am a doofus.
I had a duplicate

```
productItem.forEach(function (item) {
    wrapProductName(item, ".ProductMeta__Title");
});
```

In another file but it was

```
productItem.forEach(function (item) {
wrapProductName(item, ".ProductMeta__Title a");
});
```

So it was searching for the a to apply to.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, I couldn't experiment your exact code but here you are simple and easy!

```js
  var productMeta = document.querySelectorAll(".ProductMeta__Title");
  
  
  function wrapProductName(item) {
    var linkText = item.innerHTML;
    var newText = linkText.replace("- ", "<span>");
        linkText = newText + "</span>";
        item.innerHTML = linkText    
}

    wrapProductName(productMeta[0]);
```

```html
<h1 class="ProductMeta__Title">Product title - product feature</h1>
```